# ul menu drill down change to library

Tags: jquery, html

I found a library https://github.com/grubersjoe/slide-menu that does drilling to a behavior I am looking for apart from one thing I want to change.

*[DEMO of the plugin](https://grubersjoe.github.io/slide-menu/)*

When a user clicks on a `li` which has children, the other sections are hidden to allow the user to dill through. The library adds an arrow to let the user know there are sub elements.

The change I want to make is to have the parent text be independent from the arrow. So the arrow would be for drilling through and the parent text click would do something else.

Looking through the library I came across this section:

```js
_setupSubmenus() {
            this._anchors.each((i, anchor) => {
                anchor = $(anchor);
                if (anchor.next('ul').length) {
                    // prevent default behaviour (use link just to navigate)
                    anchor.click(function (ev) {
                        ev.preventDefault();
                    });

                    // add `before` and `after` text
                    let anchorTitle = anchor.text();
                    anchor.html(this.options.submenuLinkBefore + anchorTitle + this.options.submenuLinkAfter);
                    // add a back button
                    if (this.options.showBackLink) {
                        let backLink = $('<a href class="slide-menu-control" data-action="back">' + anchorTitle + '</a>');
                        backLink.html(this.options.backLinkBefore + backLink.text() + this.options.backLinkAfter);
                        anchor.next('ul').prepend($('<li>').append(backLink));
                      
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

And I added this line

`anchor.next('ul').before('<a class="gotToChildren" href="#"> > </a>');`

after changing `submenuLinkAfter: ' ⇒'` to `submenuLinkAfter: ''`

but then the behavior does not work.

Anyone know how to achieve what I am looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the menu I added span tag beside the parent `a` tag as follows:

`<a href="http://google.de">News</a><span></span>`

`submenuLinkAfter: ' >',` can tage anything including html code

then in the library

I changed `this._anchors = this._menu.find('a');` to `this._anchors = this._menu.find('span');`

Also in `_setupEventHandlers() {` I changed this line:

`let anchor = $(event.target).is('a') ? $(event.target) : $(event.target).parents('a:first');`

to

`let anchor = $(event.target).is('span') ? $(event.target) : $(event.target).parents('span:first');`

So the `span` tags act as the drilling elements

Also changed parent title to be grabbed from the `a` tag by changing this line:

`let anchorTitle = anchor.text();`

to

`let anchorTitle = anchor.prev('a').text();`